# Laravel 5.* generating reports for printing

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm finding the most popular report generator for laravel 5 and above. I have tried `Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel` and `JASPER REPORT`. I want to know if those are the most used plugins in generating reports. If not then I want to know some list of those plugins, also with good documentation also. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Well there is no proper reporting tool for PHP, if you want to take advantage of printing reports than use dompdf to create pdf report and than print them for laravel you can use this package

https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf